# Orbifold vs étale fundamental group of complex ball quotient

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, orbifolds

Let $X$ be a quotient of the complex ball by an arithmetic group. How does the orbifold fundamental group of the complex points of $X$ compare to the étale fundamental group of $X$?

Comment: If the arithmetic group  $\Gamma$ is torsion free, then the étale $\pi_1$ is the profinite completion $\hat\Gamma$. If you treat $X$ as a stack, then this would true in general.

Comment: @DonuArapura is there a published reference for that claim?

Comment: Adding onto what @DonuArapura says, if you want the underlying normal projective variety and not the stack, you take the quotient $\Delta$ of $\Gamma$ by the subgroup generated by torsion associated with smooth components of the orbifold locus (it's standard that this is $\pi_1$ of the underlying space), then take the profinite completion of $\Delta$. (You need to be careful you aren't killing elements of finite order in the fundamental group of the underlying normal variety.)

Comment: @Ramón For my first statement, I used the comparison between the usual topological fundamental group and etale group for a complex alg. variety, which is due to Grothendieck in SGA1. For the second, I'm not sure of a good reference. Perhaps you can look at papers of Noohi.

Comment: It's also maybe worth noting that the stack and underlying analytic space notions are very, very different. The profinite completion of a lattice in $\mathrm{PU}(n,1)$ is always very big and complicated, but there are examples of ball quotient orbifolds with underlying space $\mathbb{P}^2$, so the topological and algebraic fundamental groups of the underlying space are trivial.

Comment: @Toffee so this stack is not a quotient of its coarse moduli space by a finite group action?

Comment: @Ramón It's the same as for the moduli space of elliptic curves as a quotient of the upper half plane by the modular group. The underlying analytic space is just $\mathbb{C}$, which is (topologically and algebraically) simply connected, but $\Gamma = \mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is virtually a nonabelian free group, so it's profinite completion is huge. As a moduli space, it's the quotient of $\mathbb{P}^1$ minus $3$ points (elliptic curves with level $2$ structure), where there are no orbifold issues, by the action of the symmetric group $S_3 = \mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$.